# ESP32-cam crashes on closing camera stream

Tags: c++, arduino, camera, embedded, esp32

As it says in the title. Following is the code for the cam.ino I got off of a blog.

```
#include "esp_camera.h"

WiFiServer camServer(81);
bool connected = false;
WiFiClient live_client;

String index_html = "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>\n" \
                    "<style>\n" \
                    "#content {\n" \
                    "display: flex;\n" \
                    "flex-direction: column;\n" \
                    "justify-content: center;\n" \
                    "align-items: center;\n" \
                    "text-align: center;\n" \
                    "min-height: 100vh;}\n" \
                    "</style>\n" \
                    "<body bgcolor=\"#000000\"><div id=\"content\"><h2 style=\"color:#ffffff\">HTTP ESP32 Cam live stream </h2><img src=\"video\"></div></body>";

void configCamera(){
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;

  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 2;

  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
}

//continue sending camera frame
void liveCam(WiFiClient &client){
  //capture a frame
  camera_fb_t * fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Frame buffer could not be acquired");
      return;
  }
  client.print("--frame\n");
  client.print("Content-Type: image/jpeg\n\n");
  client.flush();
  client.write(fb->buf, fb->len);
  client.flush();
  client.print("\n");
  //return the frame buffer back to be reused
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}

void http_resp(){
  WiFiClient client = camServer.available();                    
    /* check client is connected */           
  if (client.connected()) {     
      /* client send request? */     
      /* request end with '\r' -> this is HTTP protocol format */
      String req = "";
      while(client.available()){
        req += (char)client.read();
      }
      Serial.println("request " + req);
      /* First line of HTTP request is "GET / HTTP/1.1"  
        here "GET /" is a request to get the first page at root "/"
        "HTTP/1.1" is HTTP version 1.1
      */
      /* now we parse the request to see which page the client want */
      int addr_start = req.indexOf("GET") + strlen("GET");
      int addr_end = req.indexOf("HTTP", addr_start);
      if (addr_start == -1 || addr_end == -1) {
          Serial.println("Invalid request " + req);
          return;
      }
      req = req.substring(addr_start, addr_end);
      req.trim();
      Serial.println("Request: " + req);
      client.flush();
  
      String s;
      /* if request is "/" then client request the first page at root "/" -> we process this by return "Hello world"*/
      if (req == "/")
      {
          s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n";
          s += "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
          s += index_html;
          s += "\n";
          client.print(s);
          client.stop();
      }
      else if (req == "/video")
      {
          live_client = client;
          live_client.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
          live_client.print("Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame\n\n");
          live_client.flush();
          connected = true;
      }
      else
      {
          /* if we can not find the page that client request then we return 404 File not found */
          s = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n";
          client.print(s);
          client.stop();
      }
    }       
}

void startCamera() {
  camServer.begin();
  configCamera();
}

void camLoop() {
  http_resp();
  if(connected == true){
    liveCam(live_client);
  }
}
```

And this is my main.ino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  startWifi();

  startCamera();
}

void loop() {
  camLoop();
}
```

The camera stream runs fine. Once I close the browser tab, I get the following error:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d751b  PS      : 0x00060330  A0      : 0x800d763c  A1      : 0x3ffb21e0  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000e31  A5      : 0x00000004  
A6      : 0x3ffc524c  A7      : 0x00000032  A8      : 0x800d7854  A9      : 0x3ffb21a0  
A10     : 0x3ffb21c4  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000e31  A13     : 0x00000000  
A14     : 0x3ffc5260  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000019  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000010  LBEG    : 0x4008b014  LEND    : 0x4008b030  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  


Backtrace: 0x400d7518:0x3ffb21e0 0x400d7639:0x3ffb2210 0x400d2eb0:0x3ffb2230 0x400d4967:0x3ffb2250 0x400d496f:0x3ffb2270 0x400e5261:0x3ffb2290
```

I guess it's something to do with the loop becoming idle? But not sure how to fix it. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I sugest to debug your program or to add more `Serial.println("something");` to find out where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to analyze the reason for core panicing, However at your end you can debug the cause yourself. Try using ESPExceptionDecoder from [here](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) From this tool you can analyze the Exception reason easily.